# how to resolve this error in my dart file?-The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.(I am trying to get the device info)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

THIS IS THE CODE I WROTE IN MY device_info.dart file(I am trying to get the device info).

```
    import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../domain/model/model.dart';

Future<DeviceInfo> getDeviceDetails() async {
  String name = "unknown";
  String identifier = "unknown";
  String version = "unknown";
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();

  try {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      //Android
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
          name = "${androidDeviceInfo.brand} ${androidDeviceInfo.model}";
      identifier = androidDeviceInfo.id;
      version = androidDeviceInfo.version.codename;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      // iOS
      IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
      name = "${iosDeviceInfo.systemName} ${iosDeviceInfo.model}";
      identifier = iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor;
      version = iosDeviceInfo.systemVersion;
    }
  } on PlatformException {
// return default data error

    return deviceInfoPlugin(name, identifier, version);
  }
  return deviceInfoPlugin(name, identifier, version);
}
```

1.above line is showing the error:
The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.
(device_info package from pub.dev is not compatible for dart >3 so i have used device_info_plus package)

Comment: `deviceInfoPlugin` is an *instance* of a `DeviceInfoPlugin` class.  You are trying to call that object as a function, but it is not a function-like object.  I don't know what `DeviceInfo` is, but perhaps you intend to invoke the `DeviceInfo` constructor instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```dart
    return deviceInfoPlugin(name, identifier, version);
```

to:

```dart
    return deviceInfoPlugin;
```

The `deviceInfoPlugin` variable is not a function. It is an instance of the `DeviceInfoPlugin` and it already contains the `name`, `identifier` and `version` as you defined in the if statements.

Comment: Victor sir , I did change to what you told but it is Future<DeviceInfo> so it can't return an instance of DeviceInfoPlugin type

Comment: Sir, can you please make a device_info.dart file like this to get device details. Please sir I am not able to make this

Comment: Just saw your most recent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348402/how-to-resolve-this-error-in-my-dart-file-the-expression-doesnt-evaluate-to-a/76349003?noredirect=1#comment134635703_76348402) saying it is working now. Let me know if you still need the `device_info.dart`.